# Argument of type '{}[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Tags: typescript, pipe, angular7

I have to show the first letter of given string "angular" in Uppercase and also need to show only one character. So I used the below tilecase and slice pipe in angular and it's works well but it's throwing the error `Argument of type '{}[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'` when i do production build`(ng build --prod)`

For example:

Input

app.component.ts:
name = 'angular ';

app.component.html:
{{name |slice:0:1|titlecase}}

Output:
A

Please help me to resolve this error/the way to use this better.

Answer (score 0):

try.. {{ name | titlecase |slice:0:1 }}